# IIS doesn't respond to 127.0.0.1 (external IP works fine)

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, ip, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS web server - call it box.company.com. It's running IIS and if I visit http://box.company.com in a web browser (from any machine, including box.company.com), it responds correctly with our site. However, if I visit localhost/ or 127.0.0.1/ when I'm logged into box.company.com, I get a "couldn't connect to host" message.

The hosts file has only one entry - the standard "127.0.0.1 localhost" line. Pinging 127.0.0.1 works fine. Pinging localhost correctly resolves to 127.0.0.1 and works fine.

I've tried restarting IIS and restarting the DNS Cache. I had this problem once before, and restarting the server fixed it, but I'd like to know what's going on in case this happens again in the future.

Comment: A couple updates. The site also stopped responding to box.company.com locally. Restarted and now everything works again.

Answer (score 2):

What's the IIS site's binding config look like?  What this sounds like is that it's configured to listen on a specific IP (or all IPs with a specific host header), to the exclusion of localhost.

Comment: Not really sure how to format this, but... (dash means the column is empty)
(Type,Host Name,Port,IP,Binding Info)
[http,-,80,*,-],[https,-,8443,*,-],[net.tcp,-,-,-,808:*],[net.pipe,-,-,-,*],[net.msmq,-,-,-,localhost],[msmq.formatname,-,-,-,localhost]

For what it's worth, this is the same as the config on another one of our machines that doesn't have this problem

Comment: Don't place it in a comment to an answer.  It's information that is part of the question.  Edit it into your question.  Then you'll be able to format it.